# SMTPRecipientsRefused in django

Tags: django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SMTPRecipientsRefused in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623830/smtprecipientsrefused-in-django)

when i am trying to send mails through django I am getting the above error .
Can you please tell the cause of this error and how to avoid it?