# Error: SMTPRecipientsRefused 553, '5.7.1 #while working on contact form in django

Tags: python, django, smtp, sendmail

im trying to make a contact form in django 1.3, python 2.6.

Whats the reason of following error?

error:

```
SMTPRecipientsRefused at /contact/
{'test@test.megiteam.pl': (553, '5.7.1 <randomacc@hotmail.com>: Sender address
rejected: not owned by user test@test.megiteam.pl')}
```

my settings.py:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'test.megiteam.pl'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'test@test.megiteam.pl'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '###' 
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'test@test.megiteam.pl'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'test@test.megiteam.pl'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

edit: If any1 else was following djangobook, this is the part causing it:

```
        send_mail(
            request.POST['subject'],
            request.POST['message'],
            request.POST.get('email', 'noreply@example.com'), #get rid of 'email'
            ['siteowner@example.com'],
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The explanation is in the error message. Your email host is rejecting the email because of the sender address `randomacc@hotmail.com` that you have taken from the contact form.

Instead, you should use your own email address as the sender address. You can use the `reply_to` option so that replies go to your user.

```
email = EmailMessage(
    'Subject',
    'Body goes here',
    'test@test.megiteam.pl',
    ['to@example.com',],
    reply_to='randomacc@hotmail.com',
)
email.send()
```

On Django 1.7 and earlier, there isn't a `reply_to` argument, but you can manually set a `Reply-To` header:

```
email = EmailMessage(
    'Subject',
    'Body goes here',
    'test@test.megiteam.pl',
    ['to@example.com',],
    headers = {'Reply-To': 'randomacc@hotmail.com'},
)
email.send()
```

### Edit:

In the comments you asked how to include the sender's address in the message body. The `message` and `from_email` are just strings, so you can combine them however you want before you send the email.

Note that you shouldn't get the `from_email` argument from your cleaned_data. You know that the `from_address` should be `test@test.megiteam.pl`, so use that, or maybe import `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL` from your settings.

Note that if you create a message using `EmailMessage` as in my example above, and set the reply to header, then your email client should do the right thing when you hit the reply button. The example below uses `send_mail` to keep it similar to the [code you linked to](http://pastebin.com/y3UfpU1y).

```
from django.conf import settings

...
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        message = cd['message']
        # construct the message body from the form's cleaned data
        body = """\
from: %s
message: %s""" % (cd['email'], cd['message'])
        send_mail(
            cd['subject'],
            body,
            settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, # use your email address, not the one from the form
            ['test@test.megiteam.pl'],
        )
```

Comment: wanted to delete, but on the other hand didnt wanna let u go without +points :) thanks

Comment: Don't delete -- it will help the next person who googles `SMTPRecipientsRefused` :)

Comment: hm, got a question for you, considering im using this code: [http://pastebin.com/y3UfpU1y](http://pastebin.com/y3UfpU1y) how could i attach senders email adress  (or any other additional fields) in the body of sent message?