# Sending mail using python script using smtplib - Error

Tags: python-2.7, email

I am using smtplib and calling server_ssl.ehlo to send mail using my gmail account .I am trying to import the recipients as well as the mail body from a txt file. Also, it would be great if somebody can help me out on how to add attachment in the mail .

Here's my code :

```
recipients = []
names = []
f = open("listOfRecipients.txt", 'r')

recp_list = f.read().split('\n')

# load recipients from text file into a list (recipients), strip the \n from the strings
for line in recp_list:
    if len(line.split(':')) < 2:
        continue
    names.append(line.split(':')[0])
    recipients.append(line.split(':')[1])

f.close()

f1 = open('cont.txt', 'r')
msg = f1.read()
f1.close()

sub = 'Script Test - Man, am I awesome !!'

cc_recp = ['email1@gmail.com', 'email2@happay.in']


from_mail = ['59990yash@gmail.com']
to = recipients
cc = cc_recp
#to = ['deepan@happay.in', 'yash@happay.in']
msg = """From: %s\nTo: %s\nCC: %s\nSubject: %s\n\n%s""" % (from_mail, ", ".join(to), ', '.join(cc), sub, msg)
server_ssl.sendmail(from_mail, to, msg)
#server_ssl.quit()
server_ssl.close()
print 'successfully sent the mail'
```

However, I get the following error each time I run.
Note : **The mails are going file if I mention the 'To' email ids(commented out here) in the code body instead of calling from a txt file.**

```
File "mail_sender.py", line 37, in <module>
    server_ssl.sendmail(from_mail, to, msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 747, in sendmail
    raise SMTPRecipientsRefused(senderrs)
smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused: {}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: SMTPRecipientsRefused 553, '5.7.1 #while working on contact form in django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281334/error-smtprecipientsrefused-553-5-7-1-while-working-on-contact-form-in-djang)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I stumbled upon this. Make sure you are using the correct encoding on your txt file.