# sendmail: how to configure sendmail on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, sendmail

When I searched for configuring sendmail on ubuntu I din't get any clear answer, each of them assume I know what they are talking about,

I just want basic configuration to enable email sending, basically I will use it with google app engine to enable mail sending from dev server.

I already did this:

```
sudo apt-get install sendmail
```

then

```
sudo sendmailconfig
```

but I don't know what the last one actually did.

Comment: @ThiefMaster are we not migrating questions to the appropriate SE sites any more?

Comment: This question is way too old to be migrated (and it already was so when I closed it).

Comment: None of these answers worked for me. I found this online article that works for me: http://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2013/03/19/setting-up-sendmail-with-sendgrid-on-ubuntu/

Comment: @ThiefMaster define "too old" are you saying sendmail is obsolete? Think again.

Comment: @PJBrunetWhile I do think `sendmail` is obsolete (there are much better alternatives!), my comment FIVE YEARS ago was simply about the fact that we do not migrate questions that old to another SE site.

Comment: That is still broken AF in late 2019

Answer (score 152):

When you typed in `sudo sendmailconfig`, you should have been prompted to configure sendmail.

For reference, the files that are updated during configuration are located at the following (in case you want to update them manually):

```
/etc/mail/sendmail.conf
/etc/cron.d/sendmail
/etc/mail/sendmail.mc
```

You can test sendmail to see if it is properly configured and setup by typing the following into the command line:

```
$ echo "My test email being sent from sendmail" | /usr/sbin/sendmail myemail@domain.example
```

The following will allow you to add smtp relay to sendmail:

```
#Change to your mail config directory:
cd /etc/mail

#Make a auth subdirectory
mkdir auth
chmod 700 auth

#Create a file with your auth information to the smtp server
cd auth
touch client-info

#In the file, put the following, matching up to your smtp server:
AuthInfo:your.isp.net "U:root" "I:user" "P:password"

#Generate the Authentication database, make both files readable only by root
makemap hash client-info < client-info
chmod 600 client-info
cd ..
```

Add the following lines to sendmail.mc, but *before* the `MAILERDEFINITIONS`. Make sure you update your smtp server.

```
define(`SMART_HOST',`your.isp.net')dnl
define(`confAUTH_MECHANISMS', `EXTERNAL GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
FEATURE(`authinfo',`hash -o /etc/mail/auth/client-info.db')dnl
```

Invoke creation sendmail.cf (alternatively run `make -C /etc/mail`):

```
m4 sendmail.mc > sendmail.cf
```

Restart the sendmail daemon:

```
service sendmail restart
```

Comment: when trying the last command I get this


bash: My test email being sent from sendmail: No such file or directory

Comment: also what should be edited in those files to enable sending through SMTP server credentials?

Comment: Added instructions for adding a smtp relay.

Comment: thanks @Venice but when trying m4 sendmail.mc > sendmail.cf I get this error bash: sendmail.cf: Permission denied

Comment: Make sure you are doing these commands as sudo. 

Quicktip: You can create a 'sudo session' by typing 'sudo -s', then enter the sudor password.

Comment: really I appreciate helping me, and thanks for the sudo session tip.. the last thing I'm facing is this error after typing the last command m4 ....



m4 sendmail.mc > sendmail.cf
m4:sendmail.mc:101: Warning: excess arguments to builtin `define' ignored
m4:sendmail.mc:101: cannot open `/usr/share/sendmail/cf/feature/'authinfo'.m4': No such file or directory

Comment: Hmm. It looks like you have some extra quotes somewhere in here. It's complaining about the define line, probably the SMART_HOST one. Make sure it follows the pattern of define('KEY', 'VALUE'). Mise well check the other lines you put into the sendmail.mc file as well while your in there.

Comment: Regarding client-info file, there is possibility that sendmail service is running under smmsp instead root account, so you'll have to update client-info file according to this.

Comment: sorry, when you say `your.isp.net`, do I put `gmail.com` or `smtp.gmail.com` in there?

Comment: One thing that isn't clear is what replacements to make in AuthInfo:your.isp.net "U:root" "I:user" "P:password"  Specifically, how do you replace U:root and I:user

Comment: **BUGS**: sendmail.mc as m4 file honors `x' quoting.

Comment: For testing it on localhost, you can use localhost in place of your.isp.net

Comment: In case anyone else is confused, the strings inside the `sendmail.mc` file need to be in the form **BACKTICK** + your text + SINGLE QUOTE.

Comment: This was the only configuration that worked perfectly for me: https://linuxconfig.org/configuring-gmail-as-sendmail-email-relay

Comment: @JaredEitnier Thanks! This works!

Comment: I don't have an /etc/mail directory... When I do 'which sendmail' I do get /usr/sbin/sendmail so it's there but thats it. Everyone tells me to look in the /etc/mail/ directory but it's so frustrating that it isnt there.

Comment: I was concerned that this answer would be outdated but it worked well for me. My SMTP server doesn't require authentication, so I adjusted these steps by using `AuthInfo:your.isp.net "U:root" "I:user"` and omitting the `"P:password"`. The other two I left as-is and it just worked.

Comment: I know this is old, but thank you for the step-by-step. 
When we create the "auth" directory and change its permissions to 700 - is that done as root?

Comment: @emmdee Yes. Or just `sudo chmod 700 auth`

Comment: @AndrewLamarra Thanks, was just ensuring that root is supposed to be the owner. That clears it up thanks.

Comment: @Ayamei I had that too - it looked like I had sendmail installed, but yum didn't know about it. So I just ran `yum install sendmail`, yum installed it and created `/etc/mail`.

Answer (score 35):

I got the top answer working (can't reply yet) after one small edit

This did not work for me:

```
FEATURE('authinfo','hash /etc/mail/auth/client-info')dnl
```

The first single quote for each string should be changed to a backtick (`) like this:

```
FEATURE(`authinfo',`hash /etc/mail/auth/client-info')dnl
```

After the change I run:

```
sudo sendmailconfig
```

And I'm in business :)

Comment: Whether I use your fix or not, when I invoke service sendmail restart, I get fileclass: cannot open 'ATURE(authinfo,': No such file or directory

Comment: it's "FEATURE" not "ATURE", check your copy/paste

Comment: you have to paste it at a different location in the sendmail.cf (i put it just above mailer, but i still get no mail)

Answer (score 14):

Combine two answers above, I finally make it work. Just be careful that **the first single quote for each string is a backtick (`)** in file sendmail.mc.

```
#Change to your mail config directory:
cd /etc/mail

#Make a auth subdirectory
mkdir auth
chmod 700 auth  #maybe not, because I cannot apply cmd "cd auth" if I do so.

#Create a file with your auth information to the smtp server
cd auth
touch client-info

#In the file, put the following, matching up to your smtp server:
AuthInfo:your.isp.net "U:root" "I:user" "P:password"

#Generate the Authentication database, make both files readable only by root
makemap hash client-info < client-info
chmod 600 client-info
cd ..

#Add the following lines to sendmail.mc. Make sure you update your smtp server
#The first single quote for each string should be changed to a backtick (`) like this:
define(`SMART_HOST',`your.isp.net')dnl
define(`confAUTH_MECHANISMS', `EXTERNAL GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
FEATURE(`authinfo',`hash /etc/mail/auth/client-info')dnl

#run 
sudo sendmailconfig
```

Comment: I am still having problem to understand the line AuthInfo... Can you please give one example... ???

Comment: Example, my client-info has only one line, `AuthInfo:smtp.gmail.com "U:username" "P:password"`

Comment: Still with all those settings and AuthInfo i fall into SPAM list
using smtp.gmail.com with existing account from google.admin
AuthInfo: smtp.gmail.com "U:root" "I:name@domain.com" "P:password"
also tried
AuthInfo: smtp-relay.gmail.com "U:root" "I:name@domain.com" "P:password"

Comment: To clarify: `AuthInfo: smtp.gmail.com "U:yourusername@gmail.com" "P:yourpassword"`