# Sendmail in GAE dev sever doesn't show the email body

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

While working locally on the dev server, GAE doesn't send any emails out. Unless running it with the following command:

```
dev_appserver.py --enable_sendmail myapp
```

This would rely on a local sendmail to be setup.

I am using Ubuntu now for some time and I never came across something so difficult to setup.
I came across this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10359510/92153) and 5 other tutorials. The mail.log shows that the email was accepted and sent out, but google times out.

```
Jun 28 12:13:38 tp sm-mta[15964]: r5SAnXFV014925: to=<kave@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<kave@localhost.localdomain> (1000/1000), delay=00:24:05, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=210342, relay=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
```

I would be happy to give up and rely on the log files. But the command line ouput doesn't show the email body:

```
INFO     2013-06-28 11:17:40,146 mail_stub.py:140] MailService.Send
  From: admin@mydomain.com
  To: kave@gmail.com
  Subject: Invitation to join xxx
  Body:
    Content-type: text/plain
    Data length: 347
```

It is so frustrating. Any ideas please?

**Update:**
I have tried to run it with the VM arguments:

[image]

But I get this error message:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `dev_appserver.py --show_mail_body=yes`?  Once I started using it, I could see email bodies in the logs.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue a couple weeks ago.  I ended up adding the following VM arguments to eclipse when running the DevAppServer:

> -Dmail.log_mail_level=WARNING -Dmail.log_mail_body=true

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However I get an error message: `Unknown option: -D` very strange

Comment: In eclipse, make sure you are adding them as "VM arguments" and not as "Program arguments"

Comment: Thanks Robert. I have tried that, please see the updated question for screenshots. Thanks