# Unable to send mail through sendmail using neither terminal nor PHP linux

Tags: php, email, gmail, sendmail

I have installed sendmail on my linux machine(Linux Mint) and I followed : [how to configure sendmail on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359437/sendmail-how-to-configure-sendmail-on-ubuntu) on Stack Overflow.

I got no errors till the end and I successfully restarted the sendmail.

To check I tried using telnet. Here's the terminal print

```
hackathon mail # telnet 127.0.0.1 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 hackathon ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.4/8.14.4/Debian-4.1ubuntu1; Sat, 7 Mar 2015 14:59:26 +0530; (No UCE/UBE) logging access from: localhost(OK)-localhost [127.0.0.1]
HELO server
250 hackathon Hello localhost [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
MAIL from : localhostmailbox@gmail.com
250 2.1.0 localhostmailbox@gmail.com... Sender ok
RCPT to : naveenchaudhary2010@hotmail.com
250 2.1.5 naveenchaudhary2010@hotmail.com... Recipient ok
DATA
354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
Subject : Test mail
.
250 2.0.0 t279TQBC024546 Message accepted for delivery
quit
221 2.0.0 hackathon closing connection
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Though telnet says message accepted to deliver, but I see no mail neither in Inbox or Junk of recepient, nor in the sent folder of sender.

I tried using php also.
php.ini settings :

```
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port=587

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = localhostmailbox@gmail.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
;sendmail_path =
```

Here's the PHP code :

```
<?php
$to = "naveenchaudhary2010@hotmail.com";
$subject = "test";
$body = "This is a text";
$headers = 'From : "localhost" localhostmailbox@gmail.com';

$return_val = mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
if($return_val)
    echo "sent";
else
    echo "Failure :".$return_val;    
?>
```

This is also sending the error.I tried printing the return value of `mail()` which is `null`.
Please help, this is my 7th hour wasted since morning and still no success till now.

**EDIT**

Dump of strace

```
2558  <... time resumed> NULL)          = 1425817211
13250 <... read resumed> "127.0.0.1\tlocalhost\n127.0.1.1\thackathon\n\n# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts\n::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback\nfe00::0 ip6-localnet\nff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix\nff02::1 ip6-allnodes"..., 4096) = 224
2558  rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [ALRM],  <unfinished ...>
13250 close(4 <unfinished ...>
2558  <... rt_sigprocmask resumed> [ALRM], 8) = 0
13250 <... close resumed> )             = 0
2558  select(7, [4 5 6], NULL, NULL, {5, 0} <unfinished ...>
13250 munmap(0xb77a6000, 4096)          = 0
13250 fcntl64(8, F_GETFL)               = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
13250 dup(8)                            = 4
13250 fcntl64(4, F_GETFL)               = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
13250 getsockname(8, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(25), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 0
13250 open("/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
13250 fstat64(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=224, ...}) = 0
13250 mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb77a6000
13250 read(5, "127.0.0.1\tlocalhost\n127.0.1.1\thackathon\n\n# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts\n::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback\nfe00::0 ip6-localnet\nff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix\nff02::1 ip6-allnodes"..., 4096) = 224
13250 close(5)                          = 0
13250 munmap(0xb77a6000, 4096)          = 0
13250 getegid32()                       = 126
13250 setgroups32(1, [126])             = 0
13250 ioctl(8, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, 0xbf855618) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
13250 getpeername(8, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(51828), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 0
13250 stat64("/etc/resolv.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=187, ...}) = 0
13250 open("/etc/resolv.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
13250 fstat64(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=187, ...}) = 0
13250 mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb77a6000
13250 read(5, "# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)\n#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN\nnameserver 127.0.1.1\nsearch 8.8.8.8\n", 4096) = 187
13250 read(5, "", 4096)                 = 0
13250 close(5)                          = 0
13250 munmap(0xb77a6000, 4096)          = 0
13250 stat64("/etc/resolv.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=187, ...}) = 0
13250 open("/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
13250 fstat64(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=224, ...}) = 0
13250 mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb77a6000
13250 read(5, "127.0.0.1\tlocalhost\n127.0.1.1\thackathon\n\n# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts\n::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback\nfe00::0 ip6-localnet\nff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix\nff02::1 ip6-allnodes"..., 4096) = 224
13250 read(5, "", 4096)                 = 0
13250 close(5)                          = 0
13250 munmap(0xb77a6000, 4096)          = 0
13250 getsockname(8, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(25), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 0
13250 open("/etc/services", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
13250 fstat64(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=19558, ...}) = 0
13250 mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb77a6000
13250 read(5, "# Network services, Internet style\n#\n# Note that it is presently the policy of IANA to assign a single well-known\n# port number for both TCP and UDP; hence, officially ports have two entries\n# even if"..., 4096) = 4096
13250 close(5)                          = 0
13250 munmap(0xb77a6000, 4096)          = 0
13250 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
13250 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [ALRM], [], 8) = 0
13250 time(NULL)                        = 1425817211
13250 rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {0x80e56d0, [], SA_RESTART}, {0x80e56d0, [], SA_RESTART}, 8) = 0
13250 alarm(5)                          = 0
13250 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [ALRM], [ALRM], 8) = 0
13250 socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 5
13250 bind(5, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = 0
13250 connect(5, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(113), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = -1 ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
13250 close(5)                          = 0
13250 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [ALRM], [], 8) = 0
13250 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [ALRM], [ALRM], 8) = 0
13250 kill(13250, SIGALRM)              = 0
13250 --- SIGALRM {si_signo=SIGALRM, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=13250, si_uid=0} ---
13250 alarm(0)                          = 5
13250 time(NULL)                        = 1425817211
13250 time(NULL)                        = 1425817211
13250 sigreturn() (mask [])             = 0
13250 getsockopt(8, SOL_IP, IP_OPTIONS, "", [0]) = 0
13250 time(NULL)                        = 1425817211
13250 time(NULL)                        = 1425817211
13250 open("/proc/loadavg", O_RDONLY)   = 5
13250 fstat64(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
13250 read(5, "0.56 0.24 0.22 1/414 13250\n", 1024) = 27
13250 close(5)                          = 0
13250 time(NULL)                        = 1425817211
13250 stat64("/etc/mail/access.db", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
13250 lstat64("/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
13250 geteuid32()                       = 0
13250 lstat64("/etc", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
13250 geteuid32()                       = 0
13250 lstat64("/etc/mail", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISGID|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
13250 geteuid32()                       = 0
13250 open("/etc/mail/access.db", O_RDONLY) = 5
13250 fstat64(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
13250 fcntl64(5, F_SETLKW, {type=F_RDLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
13250 time(NULL)                        = 1425817211
13250 open("/sys/devices/system/cpu/online", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
13250 read(6, "0-1\n", 8192)            = 4
13250 close(6)                          = 0
13250 stat64("/etc/mail/access.db", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
13250 open("/etc/mail/access.db", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 6
13250 fcntl64(6, F_GETFD)               = 0
13250 fcntl64(6, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)   = 0
13250 read(6, "\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0a\25\6\0\t\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\10\0\0\0\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0_\v\20\0\6\10\0\0\321\326B\375\245^\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\27\20\0\0\321\215h^\1\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
13250 open("DB_CONFIG", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
13250 stat64("/var/tmp", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISVTX|0777, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
13250 time(NULL)                        = 1425817211
13250 clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1425817211, 773188844}) = 0
13250 clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1425817211, 773264483}) = 0
13250 open("/etc/mail/access.db", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 7
13250 fcntl64(7, F_GETFD)               = 0
13250 fcntl64(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)   = 0
13250 fstat64(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
13250 pread64(7, "\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0a\25\6\0\t\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\10\0\0\0\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0_\v\20\0\6\10\0\0\321\326B\375\245^\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\27\20\0\0\321\215h^\1\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096, 0) = 4096
13250 close(5)                          = 0
13250 fstat64(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
13250 fstat64(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
13250 fcntl64(7, F_SETLKW, {type=F_RDLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
13250 fstat64(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
13250 pread64(7, "\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\22\0C\17\0\r\353\17\351\17\324\17\322\17\306\17\300\17\260\17\251\17\235\17\226\17\212\17\203\17r\17l\17W\17U\17J\17C\17\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096, 4096) = 4096
13250 fcntl64(7, F_SETLKW, {type=F_UNLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
13250 fcntl64(7, F_SETLKW, {type=F_RDLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
13250 fstat64(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
13250 pread64(7, "\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\34\0\363\16\0\r\361\17\357\17\333\17\331\17\315\17\312\17\273\17\271\17\245\17\243\17\227\17\224\17\204\17}\17k\17e\17V\17T\17@\17>\0172\17-\17%\17\36\17\22\17\v\17\372\16\363\16\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\321\215h^\1\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096, 8192) = 4096
13250 fcntl64(7, F_SETLKW, {type=F_UNLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
13250 fcntl64(7, F_SETLKW, {type=F_RDLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
13250 fstat64(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
13250 fcntl64(7, F_SETLKW, {type=F_UNLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
13250 fcntl64(7, F_SETLKW, {type=F_RDLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
13250 fstat64(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
13250 fcntl64(7, F_SETLKW, {type=F_UNLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
13250 fcntl64(7, F_SETLKW, {type=F_RDLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
13250 fstat64(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
13250 fcntl64(7, F_SETLKW, {type=F_UNLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
13250 fcntl64(7, F_SETLKW, {type=F_RDLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
13250 fstat64(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
13250 fcntl64(7, F_SETLKW, {type=F_UNLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
13250 fcntl64(7, F_SETLKW, {type=F_RDLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
13250 fstat64(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
13250 fcntl64(7, F_SETLKW, {type=F_UNLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
13250 fcntl64(7, F_SETLKW, {type=F_RDLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
13250 fstat64(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
13250 fcntl64(7, F_SETLKW, {type=F_UNLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
13250 open("/etc/hosts.allow", O_RDONLY) = 5
13250 fstat64(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=425, ...}) = 0
13250 mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb77a6000
13250 read(5, "sendmail: all\n# /etc/hosts.allow: list of hosts that are allowed to access the system.\n#                   See the manual pages hosts_access(5) and hosts_options(5).\n#\n# Example:    ALL: LOCAL @some_n"..., 4096) = 425
13250 close(5)                          = 0
13250 munmap(0xb77a6000, 4096)          = 0
13250 dup2(4, 1)                        = 1
13250 time(NULL)                        = 1425817211
13250 stat64("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=265, ...}) = 0
13250 time(NULL)                        = 1425817211
13250 stat64("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=265, ...}) = 0
13250 open("/proc/loadavg", O_RDONLY)   = 5
13250 fstat64(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
13250 read(5, "0.56 0.24 0.22 1/414 13250\n", 1024) = 27
13250 close(5)                          = 0
13250 fcntl64(7, F_SETLKW, {type=F_RDLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
13250 fstat64(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
13250 fcntl64(7, F_SETLKW, {type=F_UNLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
13250 fcntl64(7, F_SETLKW, {type=F_RDLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
13250 fstat64(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
13250 fcntl64(7, F_SETLKW, {type=F_UNLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
13250 fcntl64(7, F_SETLKW, {type=F_RDLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
13250 fstat64(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
13250 fcntl64(7, F_SETLKW, {type=F_UNLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
13250 fcntl64(7, F_SETLKW, {type=F_RDLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
13250 fstat64(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
13250 fcntl64(7, F_SETLKW, {type=F_UNLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
13250 fcntl64(7, F_SETLKW, {type=F_RDLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
13250 fstat64(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
13250 fcntl64(7, F_SETLKW, {type=F_UNLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
13250 fcntl64(7, F_SETLKW, {type=F_RDLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
13250 fstat64(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
13250 fcntl64(7, F_SETLKW, {type=F_UNLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
13250 getpeername(8, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(51828), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 0
13250 getsockname(8, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(25), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 0
13250 fcntl64(7, F_SETLKW, {type=F_RDLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
13250 fstat64(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
13250 fcntl64(7, F_SETLKW, {type=F_UNLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
13250 fstat64(4, {st_mode=S_IFSOCK|0777, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
13250 fcntl64(8, F_GETFL)               = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
13250 fcntl64(8, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK) = 0
13250 fstat64(8, {st_mode=S_IFSOCK|0777, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
13250 select(9, [8], NULL, NULL, {0, 0}) = 0 (Timeout)
13250 write(4, "220 hackathon ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.4/8.14.4/Debian-4.1ubuntu1; Sun, 8 Mar 2015 17:50:11 +0530; (No UCE/UBE) logging access from: localhost(OK)-localhost [127.0.0.1]\r\n", 165) = 165
13250 read(8, 0x8bd35d8, 4096)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
13250 gettimeofday({1425817211, 849076}, NULL) = 0
13250 select(9, [8], NULL, [8], {300, 0} <unfinished ...>
2558  <... select resumed> )            = 0 (Timeout)
2558  rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [ALRM], [], 8) = 0
2558  time(NULL)                        = 1425817216
2558  time(NULL)                        = 1425817216
2558  open("/proc/loadavg", O_RDONLY)   = 8
2558  fstat64(8, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
2558  read(8, "0.60 0.26 0.23 1/414 13250\n", 1024) = 27
2558  close(8)                          = 0
2558  time(NULL)                        = 1425817216
2558  time(NULL)                        = 1425817216
2558  open("/proc/loadavg", O_RDONLY)   = 8
2558  fstat64(8, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
2558  read(8, "0.60 0.26 0.23 1/414 13250\n", 1024) = 27
2558  close(8)                          = 0
2558  time(NULL)                        = 1425817216
2558  rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [ALRM], [ALRM], 8) = 0
2558  select(7, [4 5 6], NULL, NULL, {5, 0} <unfinished ...>
13250 <... select resumed> )            = 1 (in [8], left {292, 398402})
13250 gettimeofday({1425817219, 450896}, NULL) = 0
13250 read(8, "HELO server\r\n", 4096)  = 13
13250 fcntl64(4, F_GETFL)               = 0x802 (flags O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)
13250 fcntl64(4, F_SETFL, O_RDWR)       = 0
13250 fcntl64(8, F_GETFL)               = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
13250 fcntl64(8, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK) = 0
13250 select(9, [8], NULL, NULL, {0, 0}) = 0 (Timeout)
13250 write(4, "250 hackathon Hello localhost [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you\r\n", 64) = 64
13250 read(8, 0x8bd35d8, 4096)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
13250 gettimeofday({1425817219, 451708}, NULL) = 0
13250 select(9, [8], NULL, [8], {300, 0} <unfinished ...>
2558  <... select resumed> )            = 0 (Timeout)
2558  rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [ALRM], [], 8) = 0
2558  time(NULL)                        = 1425817221
2558  time(NULL)                        = 1425817221
2558  open("/proc/loadavg", O_RDONLY)   = 8
2558  fstat64(8, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
2558  read(8, "0.55 0.25 0.23 1/414 13250\n", 1024) = 27
2558  close(8)                          = 0
2558  time(NULL)                        = 1425817221
2558  time(NULL)                        = 1425817221
2558  open("/proc/loadavg", O_RDONLY)   = 8
2558  fstat64(8, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
2558  read(8, "0.55 0.25 0.23 1/414 13250\n", 1024) = 27
2558  close(8)                          = 0
2558  time(NULL)                        = 1425817221
2558  rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [ALRM], [ALRM], 8) = 0
2558  select(7, [4 5 6], NULL, NULL, {5, 0}) = 0 (Timeout)
2558  rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [ALRM], [], 8) = 0
2558  time(NULL)                        = 1425817226
2558  time(NULL)                        = 1425817226
2558  open("/proc/loadavg", O_RDONLY)   = 8
2558  fstat64(8, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
2558  read(8, "0.51 0.25 0.22 4/413 13250\n", 1024) = 27
2558  close(8)                          = 0
2558  time(NULL)                        = 1425817226
2558  time(NULL)                        = 1425817226
2558  open("/proc/loadavg", O_RDONLY)   = 8
2558  fstat64(8, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
2558  read(8, "0.51 0.25 0.22 4/413 13250\n", 1024) = 27
2558  close(8)                          = 0
2558  time(NULL)                        = 1425817226
2558  rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [ALRM], [ALRM], 8) = 0
2558  select(7, [4 5 6], NULL, NULL, {5, 0}) = 0 (Timeout)
2558  rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [ALRM], [], 8) = 0
2558  time(NULL)                        = 1425817231
2558  time(NULL)                        = 1425817231
2558  open("/proc/loadavg", O_RDONLY)   = 8
2558  fstat64(8, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
2558  read(8, "0.55 0.26 0.23 1/412 13251\n", 1024) = 27
2558  close(8)                          = 0
2558  time(NULL)                        = 1425817231
2558  time(NULL)                        = 1425817231
2558  open("/proc/loadavg", O_RDONLY)   = 8
2558  fstat64(8, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
2558  read(8, "0.55 0.26 0.23 1/412 13251\n", 1024) = 27
2558  close(8)                          = 0
2558  time(NULL)                        = 1425817231
2558  rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [ALRM], [ALRM], 8) = 0
2558  select(7, [4 5 6], NULL, NULL, {5, 0}) = 0 (Timeout)
2558  rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [ALRM], [], 8) = 0
2558  time(NULL)                        = 1425817236
2558  time(NULL)                        = 1425817236
2558  open("/proc/loadavg", O_RDONLY)   = 8
2558  fstat64(8, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
2558  read(8, "0.50 0.26 0.23 1/412 13251\n", 1024) = 27
2558  close(8)                          = 0
2558  time(NULL)                        = 1425817236
2558  time(NULL)                        = 1425817236
2558  open("/proc/loadavg", O_RDONLY)   = 8
2558  fstat64(8, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
2558  read(8, "0.50 0.26 0.23 1/412 13251\n", 1024) = 27
2558  close(8)                          = 0
2558  time(NULL)                        = 1425817236
2558  rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [ALRM], [ALRM], 8) = 0
2558  select(7, [4 5 6], NULL, NULL, {5, 0}) = 0 (Timeout)
2558  rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [ALRM], [], 8) = 0
2558  time(NULL)                        = 1425817241
2558  time(NULL)                        = 1425817241
2558  open("/proc/loadavg", O_RDONLY)   = 8
2558  fstat64(8, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
2558  read(8, "0.46 0.25 0.23 1/411 13251\n", 1024) = 27
2558  close(8)                          = 0
2558  time(NULL)                        = 1425817241
2558  time(NULL)                        = 1425817241
2558  open("/proc/loadavg", O_RDONLY)   = 8
2558  fstat64(8, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
2558  read(8, "0.46 0.25 0.23 1/411 13251\n", 1024) = 27
2558  close(8)                          = 0
2558  time(NULL)                        = 1425817241
2558  rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [ALRM], [ALRM], 8) = 0
2558  select(7, [4 5 6], NULL, NULL, {5, 0} <unfinished ...>
13250 <... select resumed> )            = 1 (in [8], left {275, 280004})
13250 gettimeofday({1425817244, 171941}, NULL) = 0
13250 read(8, "MAIL from :localhostmailbox@gmail.com\r\n", 4096) = 39
13250 time(NULL)                        = 1425817244
13250 time(NULL)                        = 1425817244
13250 stat64("/etc/mail/service.switch", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=149, ...}) = 0
13250 lstat64("/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
13250 geteuid32()                       = 0
13250 lstat64("/etc", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
13250 geteuid32()                       = 0
13250 lstat64("/etc/mail", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISGID|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
13250 geteuid32()                       = 0
13250 open("/etc/mail/service.switch", O_RDONLY) = 5
13250 fstat64(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=149, ...}) = 0
13250 fcntl64(5, F_GETFL)               = 0 (flags O_RDONLY)
13250 fstat64(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=149, ...}) = 0
13250 read(5, "# /etc/mail/nsswitch.conf\n#\n# This is the format that sendmail expects (no colon after the service)\n# \npasswd\t\tfiles\nhosts\t\tfiles dns\naliases\t\tfiles\n", 4096) = 149
13250 read(5, "", 4096)                 = 0
13250 close(5)                          = 0
13250 open("/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY)      = 5
13250 fstat64(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=224, ...}) = 0
13250 read(5, "127.0.0.1\tlocalhost\n127.0.1.1\thackathon\n\n# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts\n::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback\nfe00::0 ip6-localnet\nff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix\nff02::1 ip6-allnodes"..., 4096) = 224
13250 read(5, "", 4096)                 = 0
13250 close(5)                          = 0
13250 stat64("/etc/resolv.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=187, ...}) = 0
13250 socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_IP) = 5
13250 connect(5, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.1.1")}, 16) = 0
13250 gettimeofday({1425817244, 174299}, NULL) = 0
13250 poll([{fd=5, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 0) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLOUT}])
13250 send(5, "*\311\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\5gmail\3com\0\0\34\0\1", 27, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 27
13250 poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
13250 recvfrom(5, "*\311\201\200\0\1\0\1\0\4\0\4\5gmail\3com\0\0\34\0\1\300\f\0\34\0\1\0\0\0002\0\20$\4h\0@\2\10\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\20\25\300\f\0\2\0\1\0\0\17\0\0\r\3ns4\6google\300\22\300\f\0\2\0\1\0\0\17\0\0\6\3ns3\300G\300\f\0\2\0\1\0\0\17\0\0\6\3ns2\300G\300\f\0\2\0\1\0\0\17\0\0\6\3ns1\300G\300\200\0\1\0\1\0\0\2B\0\4\330\357 \n\300n\0\1\0\1\0\0\2B\0\4\330\357\"\n\300\\\0\1\0\1\0\0\2B\0\4\330\357$\n\300C\0\1\0\1\0\0\2B\0\4\330\357&\n", 8192, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.1.1")}, [16]) = 198
13250 close(5)                          = 0
13250 time(NULL)                        = 1425817244
13250 time(NULL)                        = 1425817244
13250 fcntl64(4, F_GETFL)               = 0x802 (flags O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)
13250 fcntl64(4, F_SETFL, O_RDWR)       = 0
13250 fcntl64(8, F_GETFL)               = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
13250 fcntl64(8, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK) = 0
13250 select(9, [8], NULL, NULL, {0, 0}) = 0 (Timeout)
13250 write(4, "250 2.1.0 localhostmailbox@gmail.com... Sender ok\r\n", 51) = 51
13250 read(8, 0x8bd35d8, 4096)          = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

Comment: Have you checked the mail logs (e.g. `/var/log/mail.log`)? Sendmail accepts messages, but this does not mean that it actually delivers them to the mail server of hotmail.com.

Comment: @user3584460 : Yes, I did `tail -f /var/log/mail.log` and I don't see any logs, neither before nor after sending the mail.

Comment: Then I guess there might be something wrong with the `sendmail` configuration when it doesn't log anything. Anyway, you can still debug it by `telnet`-ing (just `telnet`; do not execute commands in it), then perform `strace -f -s 200 -o dump.txt -p {sendmail_pid_here}` and then continue with the `telnet` commands. You should get some meaningful output in `dump.txt`. For the record - I installed `sendmail` on `Ubuntu` and it works with the default config. Just there was problem with `/etc/hosts`, but it is probably issue with the [DO](https://www.digitalocean.com/) installation.

Comment: @user3584460 : I did take dump of strace, but I am not able to understand it. Though, I can see "Resource not available" and "Connection Timeout with smtp.gmail.com" messages. A portion of dump is attached in the EDIT

Comment: Everything looks fine with the `strace` dump. The problem is that it doesn't capture what happens after you queue the message. One potential problem I spotted though is the the line `127.0.1.1 hackathon` in `/etc/hosts`. Try changing it with `127.0.1.1 hackathon hackathon.localdomain` and see what happens. If you need more help, I think that it will be easier to debug this in chat session.

Comment: @user3584460 : Still no success, please help in chat session if possible

Comment: You can join: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72510/room-for-insane-coder-and-user3584460