# Sendmail doesn't messages correctly or they never arrived to destiny. Why?

Tags: sendmail, telnet, send

I am trying to send a mail via sendmail command in ubuntu terminal like this:

```
sendmail EMAILADDRESS
FROM: FROMADDRESS
SUBJECT: hello world
this is a test email
.
```

I don't get any error in console, but in the logs I get the next line:

```
localhost [127.0.0.1] did not issue MAIL/EXPN/VRFY/ETRN during connection to MTA-v4
```

What could I do? I don't know how to do...

Thank for helping!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sendmail: how to configure sendmail on ubuntu?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359437/sendmail-how-to-configure-sendmail-on-ubuntu)

Comment: 1) Could you provide command line options you passed to sendmail? 2) Insert empty line between email headers and email body.