# How to install sendmail for a local developer machine on a ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: php, email, ubuntu, sendmail

i tried all sorts of tutorials, for a while something worked actually. Then I installed I think APCu and moved to php 5.6, i am not sure what exactly, but it seems the php `mail()` function no longer works.

here is what I tried:

http://lukepeters.me/blog/getting-the-php-mail-function-to-work-on-ubuntu

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-setup-postfix-on-ubuntu-14-04

i removed all files and started over, does not work any longer.

I don't care if the e-mails land in the spam, all I want is receiving an email at all.

is there a way to debug?

as said in the title. This is supposed to work on a local developer machine.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10359510/3585500) could shed some light?

Comment: I actually saw that answer and i followed it step by step, including fixing the wrong ` '. No e-mail

Comment: Try exim instead: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-send-only-mail-server-exim-on-ubuntu-12-04