# How to send email from gmail account to other account using LAMPP, PHP and Sendmail/Postfix?

Tags: php, email, sendmail, postfix-mta, lampp

When trying on Windows, it is pretty simple. I have this code in the body of a PHP file:

```
$to = "synewaveltd@gmail.com";
$headers = 'From: synewavecomplaints@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$fullText = "Complaint from : " . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n" . "Name : " .
    $_POST['fullName'] . "\r\n" . $_POST['mainText'] . "\r\n";
mail($to, $_POST['subject'], $fullText, $headers);
```

And I have this `sendmail.ini` file:

```
[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=synewavecomplaints@gmail.com
auth_password=XXXXXXXXXX
force_sender=synewavecomplaints@gmail.com
```

And basically, what I want to do is send an email from an account called `synewavecomplaints@gmail.com` to a different account called `synewaveltd@gmail.com`, where the first email has a password. On Windows, this works.

Now on Linux, there is no `sendmail.ini` file that comes with LAMPP. I have been browsing all over everywhere for ways I can go around this, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359437/sendmail-how-to-configure-sendmail-on-ubuntu), but whatever I try, does not work. I even tried to use Postfix using steps from [here](https://easyengine.io/tutorials/linux/ubuntu-postfix-gmail-smtp/), but it didn't work either.

I realise that these guides may just be wrong because of how old they are, but I cannot find any recent guides to how to do this. Can anyone tell me how this can be made possible on linux?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way using Postfix or Sendmail, but I DID find a way using SSMTP.

First install SSMTP:
`sudo apt-get install ssmtp` on ubuntu.

Then, change the configuration files as such:

`/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf`:

```
root=username@gmail.com
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
rewriteDomain=gmail.com
hostname=username
UseSTARTTLS=YES 
AuthUser=username@gmail.com
AuthPass=password
FromLineOverride=YES
```

`/etc/ssmtp/revaliases`:

```
root:username@gmail.com:smtp.gmail.com:587
localusername:username@gmail.com:smtp.gmail.com:587
```

`php.ini` [the relevant sendmail part anyway]:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port=587

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/ssmtp -t
```

After doing all of this, everything worked perfectly.