# Facing connection reset and timeout error while sending email through sendmail via smtp. How to fix this?

Tags: email, ubuntu, smtp, sendmail

i've got a problem configuring sendmail to send email through smtp.
My goal is to have the ability to send mail from a php application using smtp.
I've to migrate to a new server some old legacy php application which use the standard "mail()" php function, and i can't modify the code, so i can't just use something like "phpMailer" or "pear mail package" instead.

I've followed this guide (venice answer) [sendmail: how to configure sendmail on ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359437/sendmail-how-to-configure-sendmail-on-ubuntu?answertab=active#tab-top) , and watched many other that say the same thing...

I've already installed and configured sendmail, and it works fine for sending local mail (if i send an email to root@localhost, i receive it correctly) but not for sending "normal" email..
Every time i send an email i've got these error in the mail.log file:

```
Nov 26 15:38:17 compute-prod-main-2-vm sm-mta[22434]: xAQFcH3g022434: from=<Mattia@compute-prod-main-2-vm.europe-west1-b.c.fine-command-242712.in>, size=418, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201911261538.xAQFcHXA022433@compute-prod-main-2-vm.europe-west1-b.c.fine-command-242712.in>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Nov 26 15:38:17 compute-prod-main-2-vm sendmail[22433]: xAQFcHXA022433: to=mattiabonzi@libero.it, ctladdr=Mattia (1002/1005), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30105, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (xAQFcH3g022434 Message accepted for delivery)
Nov 26 15:38:33 compute-prod-main-2-vm sendmail[22444]: xAQFcXYx022444: from=Mattia, size=80, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201911261538.xAQFcXYx022444@compute-prod-main-2-vm.europe-west1-b.c.fine-command-242712.in>, relay=root@localhost
Nov 26 15:38:33 compute-prod-main-2-vm sm-mta[22445]: xAQFcXOb022445: from=<Mattia@compute-prod-main-2-vm.europe-west1-b.c.fine-command-242712.in>, size=469, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201911261538.xAQFcXYx022444@compute-prod-main-2-vm.europe-west1-b.c.fine-command-242712.in>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Nov 26 15:38:33 compute-prod-main-2-vm sendmail[22444]: xAQFcXYx022444: to=mattiabonzi@openworks.it, ctladdr=Mattia (1002/1005), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30080, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (xAQFcXOb022445 Message accepted for delivery)
Nov 26 15:38:37 compute-prod-main-2-vm sm-mta[21588]: xAQFXbC8021586: timeout waiting for input from authsmtp.securemail.pro during client greeting
Nov 26 15:38:37 compute-prod-main-2-vm sm-mta[21588]: xAQFXbC8021586: to=<mattiabonzi@libero.it>, delay=00:05:00, xdelay=00:05:00, mailer=relay, pri=120418, relay=authsmtp.securemail.pro [81.88.48.66], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with authsmtp.securemail.pro
Nov 26 15:41:00 compute-prod-main-2-vm sm-mta[21743]: xAQFa0cV021741: timeout waiting for input from authsmtp.securemail.pro during client greeting
Nov 26 15:41:00 compute-prod-main-2-vm sm-mta[21743]: xAQFa0cV021741: to=<mattiabonzi@libero.it>, delay=00:05:00, xdelay=00:05:00, mailer=relay, pri=120418, relay=authsmtp.securemail.pro [81.88.48.66], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with authsmtp.securemail.pro
Nov 26 15:42:02 compute-prod-main-2-vm sm-mta[21765]: xAQFb1PN021763: timeout waiting for input from authsmtp.securemail.pro during client greeting
Nov 26 15:42:02 compute-prod-main-2-vm sm-mta[21765]: xAQFb1PN021763: to=<mattiabonzi@libero.it>, delay=00:05:01, xdelay=00:05:01, mailer=relay, pri=120418, relay=authsmtp.securemail.pro [81.88.48.66], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with authsmtp.securemail.pro
Nov 26 15:43:06 compute-prod-main-2-vm sm-mta[22415]: xAQFNe4X021461: to=<mattiabonzi@libero.it>, delay=00:19:26, xdelay=00:05:00, mailer=relay, pri=210466, relay=authsmtp.securemail.pro [81.88.48.66], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection reset by authsmtp.securemail.pro
Nov 26 15:43:06 compute-prod-main-2-vm sm-mta[22415]: xAQFH7gj020614: to=<mattiabonzi@libero.it>, delay=00:25:59, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=300466, relay=authsmtp.securemail.pro, dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection reset by authsmtp.securemail.pro
Nov 26 15:43:06 compute-prod-main-2-vm sm-mta[22415]: xAQFBfZq020461: to=<mattiabonzi@openworks.it>, delay=00:31:25, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=300469, relay=authsmtp.securemail.pro, dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection reset by authsmtp.securemail.pro
Nov 26 15:43:06 compute-prod-main-2-vm sm-mta[22415]: xAQEkePb016232: to=<mattiabonzi@openworks.it>, delay=00:56:26, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=390469, relay=authsmtp.securemail.pro, dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection reset by authsmtp.securemail.pro
Nov 26 15:43:06 compute-prod-main-2-vm sm-mta[22415]: xAQEkfdA016262: to=<mattiabonzi@openworks.it>, delay=00:56:25, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=390469, relay=authsmtp.securemail.pro, dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection reset by authsmtp.securemail.pro
Nov 26 15:43:06 compute-prod-main-2-vm sm-mta[22415]: xAQEkgiG016272: to=<mattiabonzi@openworks.it>, delay=00:56:24, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=390469, relay=authsmtp.securemail.pro, dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection reset by authsmtp.securemail.pro
Nov 26 15:43:06 compute-prod-main-2-vm sm-mta[22415]: xAQEkfEJ016252: to=<mattiabonzi@openworks.it>, delay=00:56:25, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=390469, relay=authsmtp.securemail.pro, dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection reset by authsmtp.securemail.pro
```

This is what i've initialy added to the sendmail.mc file

```
define(`SMART_HOST',`authsmtp.securemail.pro')dnl
define(`confAUTH_MECHANISMS', `EXTERNAL GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
FEATURE(`authinfo',`hash /etc/mail/auth/client-info')dnl
```

I've made some research and understood that the problem may be the port that sendmail is using for the smtp connection.
i've tried to telnet my isp and i'm able to contact it only on port 465, but i cannot find a way to change the port that sendmail is using.

I've tried to add those line, but with no luck:

```
define(`ESMTP_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 465')dnl
define(`RELAY_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 465')dnl
```

I've also noticed that one antoher server that i have with sendmal instaled and propely configured is using the mailer `esmtp`, this installation use insted `relay`, is that normal?

What i'm doing wrong?
Thank yuo in advance, hope that i've listed all the relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

First find more info.  Force delivery retry in verbose mode with SMTP session tracking.
It provides useful hints in most cases (well above 50% based on my experience).

To push email with queue id `xAQEkfEJ016252` as root execute the following command:

```
sendmail -v -qIxAQEkfEJ016252
```