# How to configure sendmail to receive email from one recipient only and reject everything else?

Tags: sendmail

I am trying to figure out how to configure sendmail to receive email from one recipient only. I want to reject email sent by everyone else. I would appreciate any sort of help.

Comment: Hi Jared, Stack Overflow is geared more toward programming and software development. I think your question would be more appropriate on [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/) or maybe [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I do see sendmail related questions on stackoverflow such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359437/sendmail-how-to-configure-sendmail-on-ubuntu. My question is how to configure the access database for the above rule?